# Using Javascript to configure a googleVis event listener in Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, googlevis

Basically, I have a [gvisCalendar](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/googleVis/functions/gvisCalendar) Chart from the googleVis package in a Shiny app, and I want to display a dataTable underneath the chart that corresponds to a selected box.

I can add an event listener by setting the **gvis.listener.jscode** argument to a variable that holds a string of javascript code. For example, using this code, I can pull up the wikipedia page for a selected calendar date:

```
output$dates_plot <- renderGvis({
      gvisCalendar(calendar.ddply,
                   options = list(
                                  colorAxis = "{
                                      minValue: 0,  
                                      colors: ['E9967A', 'A52A2A']
                                   }",
                  gvis.listener.jscode = jscode2 )
          )
    })

    jscode2<- "window.open('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'
              + data.getValue(chart.getSelection()[0].row,0)); "
```

Using this code, I ran my program, selected the "June 16, 2015" box, and a new tab came up on my browser for this website: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tue_Jun_16_2015_00:00:00_GMT-0400_(EDT)

I don't actually want to do anything with wikipedia, I was just using that as an example.

All I want to do is save the date of the selected calendar box as an R object so that I can then display a data table of data that corresponds to that date.

I have almost no experience with javascript.
Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Shiny.onInputChange` to send data back to the server.
Here is an example:

```
library(shiny)
library(googleVis)
server <- function(input, output) {
        output$dates_plot <- renderGvis({
                gvisCalendar(Cairo,
                             options = list(
                                     colorAxis = "{
                                      minValue: 0,  
                                      colors: ['E9967A', 'A52A2A']
                                   }",
                                     gvis.listener.jscode = "
                                     var selected_date = data.getValue(chart.getSelection()[0].row,0);
                                     var parsed_date = selected_date.getFullYear()+'-'+(selected_date.getMonth()+1)+'-'+selected_date.getDate();
                                     Shiny.onInputChange('selected_date',parsed_date)")
                )
        })
        output$date <- renderText({
               input$selected_date
        })
}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage( 
        htmlOutput("dates_plot"),
        textOutput("date")
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In this example I parsed the date to YYYY/M/D, if you want to keep the javascript long date format you can also return `selected_date.toString()` instead of `parsed_date`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate it

Comment: NicE's solution works great as a regular shiny app.  However, when the code is moved into a shiny module, the textOuput("date") doesn't print anymore.  I suspect this is due to the name space.  Not sure if shinyjs would work here.

Comment: Just want to share the solution provided by [Joe Cheng at the comment section of the article](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html) so the code from NicE would work within a shiny module.